# is there a way to test all 5XX or 4XX codes with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

Hi everyone I'm working in a microservice which has dependency in another ones. I'm handling the rest consumption with `Restemplate` and everything its okay with that but  I also need get a 100% on sonar test coverage.

On test stuff I'd like to cover any possibility of 4XX or 5XX code to be sure of the behavior of my app. This is the code of one of my tests:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("GetAfiliations: 5XX Exception")
void getAfiliationsWithError5XX() throws IOException, InternalException {

    ContainerGetExternalAfiliations containerGetExternalAfiliationscontainerGetExternalAfiliations = mapper.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jsons/afiliacion.json")
            , ContainerGetExternalAfiliations.class);

    RequestGetAfiliations req = new RequestGetAfiliations();
    req.setDate(LocalDate.now());

    String requestString = mapper.writeValueAsString(req);

    this.server
            .expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo(URL_GET_AFILIATION))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(content().json(requestString))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY));



    Throwable exceptionThatWasThrown = assertThrows(InternalException.class, () -> afiliationsBO.getAfiliations("UID"));
    assertTrue(exceptionThatWasThrown.getMessage().contains("Error handlig external service"));

    this.server.verify();
}
```

as you can see in the test above I'm only handling a 502 http error but if i'd like to test 500 I'll need another test and for 503 one more and so on.

Anyone knows a way to test every 5XX or 4XX in only one test?

Thanks so much for reading me.

Comment: A [the 100% test fallacy](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=100%25+test+fallacy&t=h_&ia=web). Those are different tests so don't try to write 1 test for this and also push back on the 100% test coverage as 100% coverage doesn't make sense.

Comment: It sounds a bit overkill indeed, especially if you're just rethrowing a generic exception saying "an error occured". --- Add test cases for HTTP code where you actually care about the value, that is where you'll do something specific to the code / set of codes. --- But if you just want to rethrow an error, then just write a test saying that it will fail if the status code is not OK. Use 2-3 different values to document the fact that it covers any 4XX 5XX but that's it. --- You could parameterize the test with all the possible status codes, that would be more damaging imo.

Answer (score -1):

```
<...>
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is5xxServerError());
```

If you use "withStatus", you're only check that one (504: BAD_GATEWAY in your case). You need methods like is1xxInformational, is2xxSuccessful, is3xxRedirection and so on, the whole list is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE_to_4.0.3.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#is1xxInformational--).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.